# Trying to enter search data after using bash shell on Android to open a browser

Tags: python, android, bash, android-intent, termux

What I am trying to do is on an Android phone, using Termux, create a bash shell that prompts the user for input, opens a browser, takes the user input and enters it into a field in the browser that was opened. I have the code in python, but I'm trying to convert it into something my Android phone can use. The code works in python on my phone but does not open a browser, I've found that using Termux and bash shells works a bit better.

So basically what I want to do is: 
Prompt user for input -> Open a web page -> Automatically enter the input taken from the user

**Here is the code I have so far:**

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter the phone number, separate each number group with a space: " areaCode middle3 last4

am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://www.411.com/phone/
```

**Here is the example python code that I am trying to replicate that works:**

```
import webbrowser

areaCode = input("What is the area code of the phone number? ")
middle3 = input("What are the middle 3 digits? ")
last4 = input("What are the last 4 digits? ")

phoneNumber = str(areaCode) + str(middle3) + str(last4)

fourOneOne = "https://www.411.com/phone/" + "1-" + str(areaCode) + "-" + str(middle3) + "-" + str(last4)
webbrowser.open(fourOneOne)
```

The python code pulls up the website and enters the user input data automatically and that is what I'm trying to replicate using android intent. I've read a bit about the android intent function I used in my example code, I've tried using --eial areaCode and --elal areaCode just to try to test and see if I could pass data into the command, but with no success.

If anyone could help or point me in the direction so that I may try to learn myself that would be greatly appreciated. I'm a beginner when it comes to programming, this is also my first post on stackoverflow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From Termux terminal you can use command:

`termux-open-url "https://stackoverflow.com/"`

You can run this command from python via Popen or run from bash native.